# Method Parameters Gets All Inputs Instead of Just Double Inputs

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**Background**

I am working on this Java program that finds the best route from four (x,y) coordinates with one token label assigned to each individual coordinate. The program gets the distance between the first and fourth coordinate, represented by `double totalPathLength`. Next the program gets the distance between the first and second coordinate, represented by `double partOfPathLength`. The program will also get the distance between the first and third coordinate with `double partOfPathLength` as a seperate route. The program will then return `totalPathLength - partOfPathLength;` inside the method `oneRoute()`.

**Additional Information**

I called the method `oneRoute()`, to my main method, and inputted the variables storing the double input values as parameters. I also assigned the method call to doubles with path1 and path2.

**Problem/Issue**

However when I outputted `oneRoute()`, the drJava wants me to input all characters and doubles instead of inputting just doubles.

**Questions**

How can I have the program get the input of only doubles, from a bunch of `int`, `double`, `String`, and `char` inputs? How can I have the program get the input of only characters seperate from double inputs?

**Expected/Wanted Result**

I want to use the inputs of only doubles to calculate the shortest distance and compare the distance of path1 and path2 to find the shortest distance. Then I can print out the characters representing the coordinates with the shortest distance to travel like "A-T-F" and the shortest distance/best route.

**Full Java Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BestRoute {
  public double sqr(double a) {
    return Math.pow(a , 2);
  }
  
  public double distance2p(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return Math.sqrt(sqr((x2 - x1)) + sqr((y2-y1)));
  }
  
  //sqrt((p3x - p1x)^2 + (p3y - p1y)^2) == Length of entire path.
  public double getPathLength(double p1x, double p1y, double p2x, double p2y, double p3x, double p3y) {
    return distance2p(p1x, p1y, p3x, p3y);
  }
  
  //sqrt((p2x - p1x)^2 + (p2y - p1x)^2) == Length of part of path.
  public double printDistance(double p1x, double p1y, double p2x, double p2y) {
    return distance2p(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y);
  }
  
  //getPathLength() - PrintDistance() to get one Route.
  public double oneRoute(double p1x, double p1y, double p2x, double p2y, double p3x, double p3y) {
    double totalPathLength = getPathLength(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, p3x, p3y);
    double partOfPathLength = printDistance(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y);
    
    return totalPathLength - partOfPathLength;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double ApX, ApY, BpX, BpY, CpX, CpY, DpX, DpY;
    char A, B, C, D;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    A = input.next().charAt(0);
    ApX = input.nextDouble();
    ApY = input.nextDouble();
    
    B = input.next().charAt(0);
    BpX = input.nextDouble();
    BpY = input.nextDouble();
    
    C = input.next().charAt(0);
    CpX = input.nextDouble();
    CpY = input.nextDouble();
    
    D = input.next().charAt(0);
    DpX = input.nextDouble();
    DpY = input.nextDouble();
    
    //oneRoute(ApX, ApY, BpX, BpY, DpX, DpY);
    //oneRoute(ApX, ApY, CpX, CpY, DpX, DpY);
    //Asign individual route to a letter combination.
    
    BestRoute bR = new BestRoute();
    
    double path1 = bR.oneRoute(ApX, ApY, BpX, BpY, DpX, DpY);
    
    double path2 = bR.oneRoute(ApX, ApY, CpX, CpY, DpX, DpY);
    
    
    
    //System.out.println("Coordinate 1: " + A + " " + ApX + " " + ApY + " " + "Coordinate 2: " + B + " " + BpX + " " + BpY);
    
    //System.out.println("Coordinate 3: " + C + " " + CpX + " " + CpY + " " + "Coordinates 4: " + D + " " + DpX + " " + DpY);
    //System.out.println(A+B+C+D);
    
    
    //Print which path is less than the other for shorter route by calculating (first, second, last), or (first, third, last).
    //Get first two coordinates via printDistance() and substract the result of it.
    //Do the same for the second coordinates.
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some example inputs?  Where are C, D and their coordinates getting their values from?  I presume this file is the BestRoute class, if you were to give us the whole file it would be easier to copy it into our own IDEs to run so we can help you figure out what to do :)

Comment: Alright I'll edit it now.

Comment: "Gets all inputs..." Well, yes, that's what you asked each `input.next*` to do. If you only want doubles, then remove each `input.next()` call.

Comment: Yes I want to get all inputs. What I meant was to get the inputs that have doubles and use them, seperate from the character inputs. The double inputs will then be used in a conditional operator or if statement to find which route is shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Thoughts: 1) why are you passing three points into getPathLength()?  You only use the first and third.  2) method printDistance() needs to be renamed, it doesn't print anything.  It's effectively a duplicate of getPathLength().  3) could you please show us some sample input?  You have written the code to expect a mix of characters and doubles, so you either need to give the code what you have told it to expect, or change the code to expect something different.

Comment: Response: I reused some methods and code snippets. That is why there are empty arguments and such. Sample inputs in brackets: [A 0 0 B 1 1 C 2 2 D 3 3], [A 0 0 B 1 1 C 2 2 D 1.9 1.9], and [D 100.0 0.0 C 100.0 55.0 Q 100.0 -22.0 G 122.0 2.2].

Comment: I figured the solution to my problem. It was finish the entire code. The solution is unlrelated the the question though...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [sunrise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13754100/sunrise) and [OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) for helping me. :)

Answer: Finish the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BestRoute {
  public double sqr(double a) {
    return Math.pow(a , 2);
  }
  
  public double distance2p(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return Math.sqrt(sqr((x2 - x1)) + sqr((y2-y1)));
  }
  
  //sqrt((p3x - p1x)^2 + (p3y - p1y)^2) == Length of entire path.
  public double getPathLength(double p1x, double p1y, double p3x, double p3y) {
    return distance2p(p1x, p1y, p3x, p3y);
  }
  
  //sqrt((p2x - p1x)^2 + (p2y - p1x)^2) == Length of part of path.
  public double getPartLength(double p1x, double p1y, double p2x, double p2y) {
    return distance2p(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y);
  }
  
  //getPathLength() - PrintDistance() to get one Route.
  public double oneRoute(double p1x, double p1y, double p2x, double p2y, double p3x, double p3y) {
    double totalPathLength = getPathLength(p1x, p1y, p3x, p3y);
    double partOfPathLength = getPartLength(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y);
    
    return totalPathLength - partOfPathLength;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double ApX, ApY, BpX, BpY, CpX, CpY, DpX, DpY;
    char A, B, C, D;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    A = input.next().charAt(0);
    ApX = input.nextDouble();
    ApY = input.nextDouble();
    
    B = input.next().charAt(0);
    BpX = input.nextDouble();
    BpY = input.nextDouble();
    
    C = input.next().charAt(0);
    CpX = input.nextDouble();
    CpY = input.nextDouble();
    
    D = input.next().charAt(0);
    DpX = input.nextDouble();
    DpY = input.nextDouble();
    
    //oneRoute(ApX, ApY, BpX, BpY, DpX, DpY);
    //oneRoute(ApX, ApY, CpX, CpY, DpX, DpY);
    //Asign individual route to a letter combination.
    
    BestRoute bR = new BestRoute();
    
    double path1 = bR.oneRoute(ApX, ApY, BpX, BpY, DpX, DpY);
    
    double path2 = bR.oneRoute(ApX, ApY, CpX, CpY, DpX, DpY);
    
    System.out.println((path2 < path1)? "Best Route: " + A + "-" + C + "-" + D : "Best Route: " + A + "-" + B + "-" + D);
    
    System.out.println(path1 + " " + path2);
    
    //System.out.println("Coordinate 1: " + A + " " + ApX + " " + ApY + " " + "Coordinate 2: " + B + " " + BpX + " " + BpY);
    
    //System.out.println("Coordinate 3: " + C + " " + CpX + " " + CpY + " " + "Coordinates 4: " + D + " " + DpX + " " + DpY);
    
    
    //Print which path is less than the other for shorter route by calculating (first, second, last), or (first, third, last).
    //Get first two coordinates via printDistance() and substract the result of it.
    //Do the same for the second coordinates.
    
  }
}
```

Note:
I still get the wrong value when I plug the path1 and path2 to:
`System.out.println((path2 < path1)? "Best Route: " + A + "-" + C + "-" + D : "Best Route: " + A + "-" + B + "-" + D);` and don't know why.